# C# Chart: How to draw a plot over time

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

So far I have been successful in plotting a chart with the following code, but I want it to draw and connect the data points over time, not just all at once. For example, I might want it to take a total of 60 seconds to plot all of the points. How can I do this?

```
chart1.Series["test1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
chart1.Series["test1"].Color = Color.Red;

chart1.Series["test2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;
chart1.Series["test2"].Color = Color.Blue;  

Random rdn = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    chart1.Series["test1"].Points.AddXY(rdn.Next(0,10), rdn.Next(0,10));
    chart1.Series["test2"].Points.AddXY(rdn.Next(0,10), rdn.Next(0,10));
}
```

Comment: Do you want to spread the plotting of the data points over a specified amount of time, or do you want to plot the points at a fixed rate until they have all been plotted?

Comment: The latter actually.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `DispatcherTimer` and set its `Interval` to the amount of time you want to wait between points plotted.  Give it a `Tick` event handler that adds the next point to the chart, and disable the timer when you're done.

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1d),
            };

var pointsRemaining = 50;
var r = new Random();

timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
              {
                  if (--pointsRemaining == 0)
                      timer.Stop();

                  chart1.Series["test1"].Points.AddXY(r.Next(0,10), r.Next(0,10));
                  chart1.Series["test2"].Points.AddXY(r.Next(0,10), r.Next(0,10));
              };

timer.Start();
```